# How does air density affect corona discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, pressure, density

I'm wondering how local air pressure and density affect the amount of ionizations occurring in a corona discharge. Also, does the threshold voltage required for a corona discharge vary with air pressure/density?

All papers i've found so far only examine corona discharges at sea level pressure.

Comment: Have a look at Paschen's law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen's_law